# I can't save array inside redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In Home screen, I get songs from API and save it in the component state, Now after i render the songs and when i press to any of them i dispatch an action to save all songs in **redux state** and dispatch other action to appear a bottom player "true/false" **But** i got this error

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions

I don't know why it appears, it's just an array i want to save!

Home screen

```
 _renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const {url} = this.state;
    return (
      <TouchableNativeFeed
        key={item.id}
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(
            'index-recent_tunes',
            index,
            this.state.recent_tunes,
          ); // I can see the output "array of songs" + index
          this.props.saveSongs(this.state.recent_tunes, index);
          this.props.isPlaying(true);
        }}
    .....
}


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    isPlaying: _isPlaying => {
      dispatch(isPlayingAction(_isPlaying));
    },
    saveSongs: (songs, index) => {
      dispatch(songsInPlayerAction(songs, index));
    },
  };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

#### Redux

**Reducer**

```
import {SONGS_IN_PLAYER} from '../actions/types';

let initialState = {
  allSongs: [],
  currentIndex: 0,
};

const songsInPlayerReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SONGS_IN_PLAYER:
      return {
        ...state,
        allSongs: action.songs,
        currentIndex: action.index,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default songsInPlayerReducer;
```

**Action**

```
import {SONGS_IN_PLAYER} from './types';

export const saveSongsPlayer = (songs, currentIndex) => {
  return {
    type: SONGS_IN_PLAYER,
    songs,
    currentIndex,
  };
};
```

**Store**

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   ....
  songsInPlayer: songsInPlayerReducer,
  ....
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);


export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

Comment: You are dispaching `songsInPlayerAction` but the accion name is `saveSongsPlayer`

Comment: put these functions in your action file 
```
saveSongs = (songs, index) => {
      dispatch(songsInPlayerAction(songs, index));

isPlaying= ( _isPlaying ) => {
      dispatch(isPlayingAction(_isPlaying));
    }
    }``` it will work smoothly

and it will be better to connect actions like this ```export default connect(null, {saveSongs, isPlaying})(Home);```

Comment: @Victor thanks, you're right!

Comment: @RishiSahu That's means dispatch two actions at the same time? And when I want to invoke it on Home screen should I write `this.props.saveSongs(songs,index); this.props.isPlaying(true)` so what's the difference?

Comment: your action `saveSongsPlayer` returns ` { type, songs, currentIndex,};` yet your reducer is storing `action.index`. But it should be `action.currentIndex`